# Can we conclude more than the population difference with Chi Squared

Tags: chi-squared-test

I am confused about the application of Chi squared testing on the following example.  Men and Women arriving at a destination by bus,train,car,tram and foot:

```
Category    M    W     OM      OW      p  
bus      847   3862  1157    7245     0.00000000014425559150
train   1120   3589  1456    6946     0.00000000000000000055
car     2056   2653  4904    3498     0.00000000000000000000
tram     500   4209   715    7687     0.00007423333436465974
foot     165   4544   153    8249     0.00000000267538733653
```

Where 'M' and 'W' relate to numbers in the category for men and women and 'OM' and 'OW' are men and women who don't fall into the category.

p values are vanishingly small if we test the null hypothesis that men and women are equally to arrive at the destination by bus, train etc.  Therefore we reject - so we say there is a difference.  Are we saying only that the populations are different or are we saying that one is more likely to arrive by say bus than the other.  Can we conclude that the tram populations are more similar than the train populations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chi Squared test gives you a measure of confidence on the underlying difference in populations. It may be useful to look at the relative differences in populations:

```
Category    M     W     Diff
bus        58%    65%   7%
train      57%    66%   9%
car        70%    57%   -14%
tram       59%    65%   6%
foot       48%    64%   16%
```

As you can see, the tram populations are more similar than the train populations, and given that your Chi Squared is pretty good for both of them you can confidently make that statement. That said, Chi Squared is telling you that the differences are statistically significant, not that some populations may be more different than others. It is the underlying population difference that determines that, Chi Square only supports that argument.

Comment: That really helps - so I can say for example that we can reject the null hypothesis and claim the alternative that more men travel by car than women with a p < 0.05.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right!